# Access Violation Exception in MembershipProvider.CreateUser method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nunit, specflow

Recently, I was lucky enough to upgrade my machine to the new Lenovo Yoga 2 pro and the following problem only **occurs on this machine** (windows 8.1 - not pro unfortunately.)

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 2. The exact line of the "accessViolationException" is thrown when calling the very old aspnet MembershipProvider.CreateUser method. It happens only when I run from a Test Project that uses specflow and nunit so I can setup a user for the scenario.

The only thing that I can think of is hardware/driver problem? But even so, how would I identify the culprit? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Ok. Attached the image with the view details. Not sure if it's enough...

[image]

Comment: "View detail..." would be a good place to start... (and "copy exception detail") and add it to your question.

Comment: Try to run it without specflow.

Comment: Sometimes this can be caused by 32 bit vs 64 bit issues. Check what your app is compiled to and see if changing that helps.

Comment: is your new machine 64 bit and your old machine 32 bit?

Comment: have the same problem here, the configuration is as yours

Comment: Ok, so to add to the mystery... When I have tried adding the user through the website (not actually using nunit and specflow) it works just fine. 

The only difference here though, is that the Membership.CreateUser method isn't called directly, but the old create user wizard forms server control is used.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate this is quite an old question but I lost several days to this and wanted to post my solution. I hit this exact same issue when using the MembershipProvider in Visual Studio 2013 (calling FindUserByEmail or CreateUser), more specifically I was using the [SqlMemberProvider implementation](https://bensteinhauser.wordpress.com/2012/07/16/using-the-sqlmembershipprovider/) (i.e. I hadnt implemented my own membership provider) and it turned out to be an issue with SQL Data Client mentioned in [KB2915689](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2915689). The scenarios listed didnt match mine but downloading version 4.5.2 of the .Net Framework mentioned in the resolution of that KB article fixed the issue.

Hope that saves someone else some time.